# Execute all Query or Nothing Should get executed

Tags: sql

Well Try to Format Ques.I have set of Queries mentioned below.Now i want to have some functionality which can ensure either all query should execute or not even one(if some kind of error occur) i just want to maintain my database in proper state.

```
    con.setAutoCommit(false);
                                    String qry = "insert into tblAllotment(Employee_ID,Employee_Name,Area,Building_Name,Flat_Type,Flat_No,Date_Application,Date_Allotment,Admin_Code) values(" + id + ",'" + name[1] + "','" + area + "','" + flat[2] + "','" + flat[1] + "','" + flat[0] + "','" + dte + "','" + date + "'," + uid + ")";
                                    String qry1 = "insert into tblFlat_Report(Flat_No,Area_Code,Employee_ID,Date_Allottment,Admin_Code)values('" + flat[0] + "'," + acode + "," + id + ",'" + date + "'," + uid + ")";
                                    //String qry2="UPDATE tblUser_Report t1 JOIN (SELECT MAX(S_Date) s_date FROM tblUser_Report WHERE Employee_ID = "+id+") t2 ON t1.s_date = t2.s_date SET t1.Status = 'A', t1.S_Date ='"+date+"' WHERE t1.Employee_ID ="+id+"";
                                    String qry2 = "insert into tblUser_Report(Employee_ID,Employee_Name,S_Date,Area,Status) values(" + id + ",'" + name[1] + "','" + date + "','" + area + "','A')";
                                    String qry3 = "update tblFlat set Status ='A' where Flat_No='" + flat[0] + "' AND Area_Code=" + acode + " ";
                                    String qry4 = "update tblUser set WL_Flag='N' where Employee_ID=" + id + "";
                                    st = con.createStatement();
                                    int i = st.executeUpdate(qry);
                                    int j = st.executeUpdate(qry1);
                                    int k = st.executeUpdate(qry2);
                                    int l = st.executeUpdate(qry3);
                                    int m = st.executeUpdate(qry4);
con.commit();

                                    if (i != 0 & j != 0 & k != 0 & l != 0 & m != 0) {
                                        Done = "Data Inserted Successfully...!!!";
                                    } else {
                                        System.out.println("Error Occured");
                                    }
                                } catch (SQLException e) {
con.rollback();
                                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                                }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your database has to provide transactions. If you use MySQL, you cannot use a MyISAM <strike>database</strike> table, you have to use a InnoDB one (for example).

You begin a transaction at the start of your code, then check each result. If you get an error, you issue a rollback. If everything runs fine, you issue a commit at the end.

Your look should look like:

```
con.setAutoCommit(false); // at the beginning, to prevent auto committing at each insert/update/delete
// ... your updates, with error checking
con.commit(); // at the end, only if everything went fine.
```

In case of error, call con.rollback()

Comment: How can i Convert my whole database engine to InnoDB ?

Comment: In fact, it's a table per table process, since you can have tables in MyISAM and InnoDB in the same MySQL database. You have several options, including directly altering the engine of the table (using "alter table XXXX ENGINE=InnoDB") but I strongly suggest you read this article http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/converting-tables-to-innodb.html (may depend on your MySQL version) and check what's your best option to do it (for example, if your DB server is in production, etc)

Comment: The same documentation for MySQL 5.5 : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/converting-tables-to-innodb.html

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your queries in try catch. Add setAutoCommit(false) at the start of try and commit() at its end, add rollback() in catch block.

```
try {
    conn.setAutoCommit(false);

    // Execute queries

    conn.commit();
} 
catch (SQLException e) {
    conn.rollback();
}
```

Comment: Does your database support transactions as mentioned by other user ?

Comment: MySQL database is engine is set to "MyISAM"